# Reverse Engineering a Spreadsheet into a Model and Controller

Tags: excel, vba, model-view-controller, database-design, spreadsheet

I need some help with the approach to a specific project. We have a large excel workbook with a ton of worksheets. There are many user inputs, which formula fields pull, return, repeat. This all ends up in a final report. Each worksheet has essentially become its own Model, View and Controller :).

I want to find a way to split the "model" and "controller" - basically to create a base data dictionary and a rules engine.

Here is what I think my strategy should be:

With VBA,

1. Crawl through the workbook looking up every formula field.
2. Record the results, which kind of becomes the rules engine list.
3. Look at all of the rules generated and any input cell that isn't itself a formula field is likely a raw input field. Have these form the data dictionary.

The above approach is quite flawed - there are raw data fields that have "default values" which are generated via formula. Furthermore, there are formulas that just "fix" fields, like phone numbers. These aren't really "rules".

Before I just jump into the project, I thought I would ask if anyone has done this before, trying to reverse engineer a large workbook into a model and controller in order to create an application? Perhaps you have some insight that I am lacking (Excel is NOT my domain) or perhaps a better strategy?

Comment: This question appears too broad for this forum. You might have better luck at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ but I would read their manifest first. Personally, I would simply overview the project with as list of objectives and use the methods I've found to be best suited for each facet. tbh, I rarely encounter a workbook that couldn't use some improvement and that includes the one I created last week.

Comment: Right - this question might be too broad. I'll try posting over there as well. I've always found my best answers here though, so I risked it.

Comment: @Jeeped when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: The original MVC concept of a model described a state machine which incorporated both state and behavior, while controllers mapped user interaction to model methods.

Answer (score 0):

The flaw you mention isn't really a flaw. In Excel, a field that isn't locked for input can be overwritten by the user, so a formula on such a field always yields a default only. Of course, many spreadsheet designers don't care for locking calculated results for input and just rely that nobody will overwrite the result. But if you want to create an application with exactly the same semantics of the one you have, you will have to treat such a formula/rule as overwriteable.

It will be up to your knowledge of the underlying domain to decide which fields should be locked for input. That depends on whether there is an alternative way to decide on the field value apart from using the formula.